# How to write a command line program which can be accessed by a separate frontend?

Tags: python, user-interface, frontend

I've been writing command line applications (mainly in Python) for quite a while now, and I've also been doing a bit of GUI programming using (Py)Qt. In the GUI program's I've written, the programs logic and the GUI were often quite integrated. I am now wondering however, how I could write a GUI front end, for the pure command line programs which I've written. Or in other words; how do I write a command line program so that a GUI could be developed completely separate from it?

Although I am most interested in Python implementations I think the answer could be pretty general.

Comment: If you use Qt or PyQt for GUI, you can write to command line program's stdin channel and read from command line program's stdout channel with QProcess. Or define an application protocol and communicate via TCP or UDP sockets.

Comment: Are they on the same server? I think you can take a look at messaging systems ex. 0MQ

Comment: @Vor - I've worked with zeromq before (very cool stuff), but that is not the direction I want to go for since it would mean that starting the program would mean that you would need to start two processes, which I want to avoid.

Comment: @HesamQodsi - Thanks for that suggestion. I guess that could work. Is that way (using stdin and stdout) the usual way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple, probably naïve way could be to structure your CLI program such that its main function accepts your command line arguments, so that you could import it and call it with the options set in the GUI.

I've never tried it, my guess is that it could work with simple "pure" CLI programs (ie, you run it, it does its jobs, and only then prints its output), but could get unwieldy with interactive program needing to prompt the user or with a lot of output.

Comment: The interactive nature of the CLI-program is indeed what concerns me. For example, what if it needs input, how could you easily convert that to a GUI?